# Angular-cli updating application settings, like ''prefix"

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to figure out is it possible to change the applications configuration values (like prefix) with a cli command?

I.e.:

1. I created a new project with ng new name
2. Added a new component wit cli ng g c comp-name

The application settings have the 'prefix' value set by default to 'app'. I haven't changed it while creating app in step 1. Now, after creating new component in step 2, I realized that the prefix 'app' is not that great.

My question is, is there is a cli command that would change the prefix in the app configuration, *and* in the code as well?

Comment: To change a setting in the config use [`ng set`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/config). It is up to you to change the value in the code.

Comment: Any IDE with a 'refactor' feature (for example, WebStorm) will allow you to easily rename the component and all references to it in one shot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng set apps.0.prefix='two'` to change the prefix.  It's up to you to refactor previous code to follow the new prefix.  Most editors can help you with this.

From my experience this does not update the values in `tslint.json`, so you'll want to change the values there as well.

For `tslint.json` you can set both component and directive rules:

```
"directive-selector": [true, "attribute", "app", "camelCase"],
"component-selector": [true, "element", "app", "kebab-case"],
```

If you want to use more than one prefix, you can specify them in an array like this([example from here](https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer#recommended-configuration)):

```
//RULES: [ENABLED, "attribute" | "element", "selectorPrefix" | ["listOfPrefixes"], "camelCase" | "kebab-case"]
  "directive-selector": [true, "attribute", ["dir-prefix1", "dir-prefix2"], "camelCase"],
  "component-selector": [true, "element", ["cmp-prefix1", "cmp-prefix2"], "kebab-case"],
```

- In the array, the first argument is a boolean for whether it is enabled or not.
- The second argument is a union type with choices attribute or element.
- The third argument is either a string for a single prefix or an array for a list of prefixes.
- And the fourth argument is a union type of either kebab-case or camelCase.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx, this helps. I was thinking there might be an update for prefixes automatically, as the refactor option might not be safe, especially when you have a large project.